# C# организация доступа к базе данных в решении с несколькими проектами

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

есть следующая структура решения, которая включает 3 проекта

```
-project
  -Program.cs
-project.Database
  -ProjectDbContext.cs
-project.Services
  -GlobalServices.cs
```

Все проекты - это либо библиотека, либо консольное приложение. Ни о каком `ASP.Net` речи не идет.
Вопрос состоит в том, как оформить `ProjectDbContext.cs`

На данном этапе это выглядит вот так

```cs
namespace project.Database
{
    public class ProjectDbContext: DbContext
    {
        private readonly string connectionString = "any_connection_string";
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

Что смущает?

1. Статичность `ConnectionString`. Добавить `IConfiguration`, чтобы забрать это значение из `user-secrets` не получается, получаю ошибку

   ```
   Unable to create an object of type 'ProjectDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time,....
   ```
2. Использование директивы `using` в других частях решения, которая имеет в себе блок `finally` и каждый раз закрывает соединение с БД.

Comment: Ошибка при миграции выдаётся? По ссылке же описано, что нужно сделать.

Comment: `Использование директивы using в других частях решения, которая имеет в себе блок finally и каждый раз закрывает соединение с БД.` нет, не закрывает, а возвращает в пул соединений ado.net

Comment: По поводу using. Класс DbContext специально спроектирован легковесным. Он является реализацией паттерна UoW (unit of work): создали его, поработали, удалили. Более того, он не является потокобезопасным, поэтому его и следует создавать именно там, где возникла необходимость, после чего диспозить.

Comment: Кстати, EF Core открывает/закрывает соединение при _каждом_ обращении к БД, а не при создании/уничтожении DbContext. Вот, например, по [ссылке](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#connection-pooling) в документации можно посмотреть лог, где видно, когда это происходит.